# App crashes when saving in different thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a method which creates a separate thread:

```
// Create thread
dispatch_queue_t uniqueQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Unique Email Queue", NULL);

// Run block on another thread called downloadQueue
dispatch_async(uniqueQueue, ^{

     // Save to core data for redundancy
        User *coreDataUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        coreDataUser.username = [emailStr lowercaseString];
        coreDataUser.email = emailStr;
        coreDataUser.name = nameStr;

        NSError *error;

        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }            
    }
```

The app always crashes on this line:

```
User *coreDataUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

I am using this tutorial as a reference: http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-core-data-tutorial-with-example/

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you get "could not locate an entity named 'User' in this model." message or something like that?

Comment: no i just get sigabrt kill_thread

Answer (score 4):

`NSManagedObjectContext` is not threadsafe, try to create new moc in side of the async block.
Try:

```
// Create thread
dispatch_queue_t uniqueQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Unique Email Queue", NULL);

// Run block on another thread called downloadQueue
dispatch_async(uniqueQueue, ^{

     // Save to core data for redundancy
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];

        User *coreDataUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        coreDataUser.username = [emailStr lowercaseString];
        coreDataUser.email = emailStr;
        coreDataUser.name = nameStr;

        NSError *error;

        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }            
    }
```

The persistent store is in your AppDelegate

Comment: I upvote your question because it's ok but you shoul provide some other info. On the contrary you should add it as a comment.

Comment: I was asking myself the same question, but I kind of gotten used to people downvoting answers for no reason :). Thank U for advice I will trie to provide more detailed answers...

Comment: Curious where is the file that it saves too?

Comment: this is still crashing for me

Answer (score 3):

Remember - CoraData is not thread safe !!!!!

If you want separate thread for your `managedObjectContext` you have to create one on this thread. To call proper context you have to run it with `performBlock` block. In your case:

```
[self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        User *coreDataUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        coreDataUser.username = [emailStr lowercaseString];
        coreDataUser.email = emailStr;
        coreDataUser.name = nameStr;

        NSError *error;

        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }   
}];
```

But remember, if you creating context on mainThread, your block is also executed on mainThread.

Comment: This is only valid for iOS 5 API.